# hover over image paragraph spacing too wide

Tags: html, css

Hi communities of stack overflow

I have a problem which I'm trying to solve for hour
after I've completed the transition css, the paragraph spacing gets too wide, and it does not push down the second box in the bottom.

I have tried line-height, but to no avail.
https://jsfiddle.net/jq2ka65y/ is my jsfiddle link.

While this is the result I'm trying to achieve
http://prntscr.com/c1ntt9 is a screenshot of my prototype.

```
                        </body>
                        </html>
```

Apologies if it's very messy. I'm still trying to get use to this.

Comment: Currently, the `divs` are overlapping, while in your image they are separated. What exactly is the effect expected ? Do you want the `divs` to be one over the other and be pushed down when you hover the one before ? Or do you want them to be displayed side to side ?

Comment: I wanted to make it when a user hover to the image. The heading text and paragraph will drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animating line-height on hover is clearly not a good idea. For a display/hide animation, I recommend you to use javascript. Wrap the section you want to hide into a `<div></div>` with the CSS `display: none;`. Then you can use the `.hover()` event of jQuery (for example) and display your section with `.slideToggle()`.
https://jsfiddle.net/alm/dLgw79av/5/

Comment: Thank you Adrien, but is there no way to only use CSS to fulfill this requirement?